# datepicker: display value from DB but allow user change; multiple datepicker()s on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm a noob wrt jquery and javascript.  So, while I've looked at a lot of SO posts that deal with a piece of my problem, I've not been able to "assemble" the various solutions into something that works for me.

My context: the results of a query are displayed in a form. In each row, one of the fields is a date with an existing value. When first rendered, the data of all fields is text (non-editable).  Via a button, I "enable" the fields for editing and I want to use jQuery datepicker for the date field.  (I have this part working.)

One requirement: dates are stored in the database in ISO ('yyyy-mm-dd') format. The date displayed in the form (formatted via php) are 'M d y'.The datepicker should use the 'M d y' format for display as well (also seems to be working), but "post" the revised date in ISO format.

I've posted my code so far below and 
[here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Transformer/5KK5W/13/)

```
<div class="container" id="myDiv">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="projID" name="projID" value="fakeProjID">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- initially form is in "display-only mode" -->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="make-editable" onClick = "toggle_edit(id,'fakeProjID');">Edit</a>
        </div>

        <!--rows dynamically generated via query
     the id of the record is appended to the ids and inserted into the data-ids, data-dateval and values
     these are fixed values for demo, but are dynamic values in reality -->
        <div class="row">

                <input type="text" name="date_pickr[]" id="date_pickr_511" class="input date_pickr disabled" data-id="511" data-dateval="2012-03-12" value="2012-03-12" disabled="true"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="fmt_date[]" id="fmt_date_511" value="2012-03-12"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="activityID[]" value="511"/>

                //more info goes here//


        </div>

        <div class="row">

                <input type="text" name="date_pickr[]" id="date_pickr_376" class="input date_pickr disabled" data-id="376" data-dateval="2013-05-19" value="2013-05-19" disabled="true"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="fmt_date[]" id="fmt_date_376" value="2013-05-19"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="activityID[]" value="376"/>

                //more fields goes here//

        </div>

        <div class="row">                       
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
//datepickers
$(function() {

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'M d y',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });

    $('.date_pickr').datepicker();

    $('.date_pickr').datepicker( 'option','altField','#fmt_date');

});

function toggle_edit(ID,projID) {
    var working_elemID = ID;
    var ItemID = projID;

    //name of modal div to enable/disable
    var group_id = 'myDiv';

    //if elem_ID = make_editable
    if (working_elemID.search('un') == -1) {

        //working code to make field editable

    } else {

        //working code to make field uneditable

    }
}
```

The parts I need help with are:
a) getting the default dates to show in the field before they are edited/editable
b) getting datepicker to open to the default date shown for that field
c) getting datepicker to set the new value to a field that is included in the $_post data (currently trying to use the hidden input field).

Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the html5 <input type=date> ?

Comment: Well the datepicker widget requires that the input type be set to "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of iteration, I've solved my own question.  Here's what I came up with:

The HTML (with PHP for the values)...

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="projID" name="projID" value="<?php echo $projID; ?>">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- initially form is in "display-only mode" -->
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="make-editable" onClick = "toggle_edit(id,'fakeProjID');">Edit</a>
        </div>

        <!--rows dynamically generated via query
     the id of the record is appended to the ids and inserted into the data-ids, data-dateval and values
     these are fixed values for demo, but are dynamic values in reality -->
    <?php 
    foreach($vals as $ky=>$v) {

        $row = '
        <div class="row">

                <input type="text" name="date_pickr[]" class="input disabled" data-id="'.$vals[$ky].'" value="'.date('M d y',strtotime($dates[$ky])).'" disabled="true"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="fmtd_date[]" id="fmtd_date_'.$vals[$ky].'" value="'.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[$ky])).'">
                <input type="hidden" name="activityID[]" value="'.$vals[$ky].'"/>

                //more info goes here//

        </div>';
        echo $row;
    }
    ?>


        <div class="row">                       
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
function toggle_edit(ID,projID) {
        var working_elemID = ID;
        var ItemID = projID;

        //if elem_ID = make_editable
        if (working_elemID.search('un') == -1) {

            var selector = '#'+ group_id +' .disabled';
            var fields = $(selector);
            fields.removeClass('disabled');
            fields.addClass('enabled');
            fields.removeAttr('disabled','');
            fields.addClass('date_pickr');
            $('.date_pickr').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'M d y',
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                firstDay: 1,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showOn: 'focus',
                onSelect: function() {
                    var id = $(this).data('id');

                    var currentDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var altFormat=$(this).datepicker('option','altFormat');
                    var formatedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(altFormat,currentDate);

                    $('#fmtd_date_'+id).val(formatedDate);
                }
            });

        } else {

            //if elem_ID == make_uneditable
            var selector = '#'+ group_id +' .enabled';
            var fields = $(selector);
            fields.removeClass('enabled');
            fields.addClass('disabled');
            fields.disabled = 'true';
        }
    }
```

And here are the explanations for each of the three questions. The key breakthrough came when I stuck the datepicker functions inside the "toggle-edit" function.

(a) The default dates (i.e. the database values) are shown by
   assigning the date value from the database (formatted by using the
   php Date() function with the exact same format as the datepicker
   dateFormat value...in this case 'M d y') into the value field of the
   datepicker input control. 
(b) When the control is enabled for editing,
   the date_pickr class is added to the control.  With the value of the
   control set to the right value and format, the datepicker
   automatically displays the correct calendar when the field receives
   focus. 
(c) the $_POST value (for writing back to the db) is set in a
   hidden input control.  At first the control receives the database
   value. If the value is edited, then the 'onSelect:' option function
   is fired and therein the id of the datepicker (which is the recordID
   for the row, from the database) is appended to the ID of the hidden
   field with the properly formatted date value.

NOTE: the php date formats are different than jQuery.  To get yyyy-mm-dd in PHP, you need 'Y-m-d'.  For jQuery, you need 'yy-mm-dd'.

Voila!  Mission accomplished, but always open to suggestions/improvements.